# Switching between navigation controller in master-details app

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, unwind-segue

I'm creating a app for IPad using master-details project (swift). In this project I've following views,

**1. Welcome view - this is the home view controller.**

**2. List view - it is table view which displays the list of employees whose information exists in database.**

**3. Add new employee view - To add new employee details.**

In Master list, 3 entries are added for each view. So, each view are with different navigation controller.
 From list view navigator I've added "+" button, when touched app will show "Add new employee view". I did this by adding a segue from "+" button to the navigation controller containing "Add new employee view". In "Add new employee view" I've added a cancel button. I want to go back to list view when this button is clicked (I've added a flag and set it when view is pushed from list view). On cancel button I'm calling "self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)". But this is not working. Also, it doesn't show any error or warning in debug console. Can anybody help out how to make it working.

Regards,
Pravanjan

Comment: Try to learn and implement -http://www.raywenderlich.com/114148/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-1-welcome-to-programming . google it .all the best

Comment: Issue is the view controller is invoked from tableviewcontroller. So, the presentedviewcontroller is set to nil. This causes the unwind segue abort. If anyone have faced the same issue and resolved, please share the solution.